# How to track memory usage in bash

Tags: bash, memory, memory-management

I have a series of bash scripts running on an embedded system.   The bash scripts include others, and when they do, it seems that their memory usage jumps up.   So for example, I have:

```
showmem() {
        echo "[$1]  $(ps up $$ | tail -1 | awk '{print $6}')"
}

showmem "about to include"
. foo.sh
showmem "done include"
```

And I get output

```
[about to include]  3356
[done include]  5244
```

Notice that the values are in Kb...   So, I need to figure out where the memory is going.  At first I thought it was the actual size of the file being included (the file includes other files etc), but I've now added up all the file sizes and they're not significant.  Also, the size of the output of `env` doesn't go up much either, so it's not a bloated environment, and the process tree is not showing any sub-processes.

Are there any tools that can tell me what the memory is being used for?   Is there any way to 'flush' unused memory at any point in a bash script?

(note: this is important because this particular bash script waits for an event, and there are several instances of it running at any given time).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not possible. The bash itself is very complicated and its memory usage may not be simply cacluated by the script it's running.